# WordPress php glob(); not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, glob

I have created a function in WordPress where I wish to obtain all the images within a given directory, for which I am using the PHP glob function, for some reason I cannot get this to work, is the glob() function disabled for use within WordPress?

The Code that Doesn't Work...

```
function getAccreditaionLogos(){

    define('ACCREDPATH', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/accreditations/');

    $images = glob(ACCREDPATH . '*.png');
    foreach($images as $key => $img):
        $get_icons = '<li><img src="'.$img.'" /></li>';
        echo $get_icons;
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: What shows `var_dump(get_stylesheet_directory_uri())`, what is in `ACCREDPATH` after all assignments?

Comment: Good Point, I am using the wrong declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` gives you a web url ( http://… )
. You have to use an absolute system path. You can get it by using the `get_theme_root()` function instead.

Your function should look like this:

```
function getAccreditaionLogos(){

    define('ACCREDPATH', get_theme_root() . '/img/accreditations/');

    $images = glob(ACCREDPATH . '*.png');
    foreach($images as $key => $img):
        $get_icons = '<li><img src="'.$img.'" /></li>';
        echo $get_icons;
    endforeach;
}
```

More [details of this function in the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_root).