# Having Issues on Using PHP glob() in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using pure PHP code inside WordPress I am having trouble on getting the `glob()` work to generate image source.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="height=600px; width=1000px;">
    <?php
     $directory = "http://geocaa.com/wp-content/themes/Booting/img/services/";
     $images = glob($directory . "*.png");
      foreach($images as $image)
       {
        echo '<div class="dynamic item">';
        echo ' <img src="'.$image.'" alt="...">';
        echo ' </div>';
       }
    ?>
</div>
```

As you can see I tried to hardcoded the `$directory` as `"http://geocaa.com/wp-content/themes/Booting/img/services/";` and also I already investigate on these two Post [[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295175/wordpress-php-glob-not-working) & [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42030975/wordpress-using-glob-returns-an-empty-array) ] regarding the same issues but the solutions there still not working for me!

The `get_theme_root()` retuns nothing but the `get_template_directory()` is returning something which is more like

```
$images = glob(get_template_directory().$directory . "*.png");
```

> /home/vcbb/public_html/wp-content/themes/geocaa/img/services/img.png

and useless for image src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$directory = "/img/services/";
$images = glob(get_template_directory().$directory . "*.png");
foreach($images as $image)
{
    echo '<div class="dynamic item">';
    echo ' <img src="'. str_replace(get_home_path(), get_home_url(), $image) .'" alt="...">';
    echo ' </div>';
}
```